# Asp.net and Azure - Can't no longer show my web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

After I updated my azure project last night I can't see my pages any more i only get the 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

I am using asp.net mvc - and it has been runing well for the past two weeks, but it seems like the routing is no longer working.

If i go directly to a page, it works, but because of security, it redicrets to cloudapp.net/login? - which gives the error 404 - File or directory not found.

How do enable the routing again?
It works fine on my local computer with the azure emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you change? If you are using any kind of source control, check the changes on web.config file along with global.asax.cs file. The routing module is automatically loaded for .NET Framework 4.0 project. There is a small chance that someone accidently changed the target framework version of the project. Other possible crash of losing the routes is the Routes registration with the RouteTable in the Application_Start event handler from the Global.asax.

Comment: I tried to make a text diff on the current file and my backup apprently the following line was deleted from my web.config
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
So now it works thanks!

Comment: Well, yes, this is the price for the web routing that comes with MVC. However, this is an interesting post on the subject - how to do the things right: http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html I personally, also don't like the RAMFAR (runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests) and would avoid it when possible!