# Deploy to azure then get 403 - Access Forbidden

Tags: azure

I'm trying to deploy to Azure (Silverlight application); I've migrated my DB, updated connection strings and published my application to Azure but when I click the service URL I get this:

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Any idea what I need to change?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to access the `.svc` URL or the directory it's in or its `wsdl` or...?

Comment: I'm trying to access the cloud service site URL once the publish has completed, everything is running and online e.g http://coedpoethservices.cloudapp.net/

Answer (score 7):

If the name of your bundle matches the path in the file system then IIS on Azure will throw the 403 Forbidden error.

So if you have a path in your solution called `/Content/css` and you have a bundle name called `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include( ...`  in `BundleConfig.cs` which is displayed like this `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` in your `_Layout.cshtml` file. Then you get that error.

I solved this by changing the name of my bundle from `/Content/css` to `/Style/css`

1. `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include( ...`  in `BundleConfig.cs` becomes `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Style/css").Include( ...`
2. `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` in your `_Layout.cshtml` becomes `@Styles.Render("~/Style/css")` in your `_Layout.cshtml`

You can use any names you like there is no specific limitations. I imagine you can go ahead and rename the folders in your solution too and that should work.

NB: The name of the bundle turns into a virtual directory that the browser can request from.  If it resembles a physical folder structure then it will throw back the **403**.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the full path to a page within the application as I hadn't set a default document in my web config e.g

```
   <add value="Pages/Home.aspx"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in my MVC project. 
After some debugging I found that it was because I have removed all "default pages" in the Azure Portal.

I added a dummy "index.html"-record in the portal and then everything worked nicely again :)